# Compare 2 binned non-parametric histograms with hypothesis test

Tags: python, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, histogram, discrete-distributions

According to this guy here: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-compare-two-distributions-in-practice-8c676904a285 and the following papers he mentions inside his article, and more specifically the 2 below:

[1] Elmore, K. L. (2005). Alternatives to the Chi-Square Test for Evaluating Rank Histograms from Ensemble Forecasts. Weather and Forecasting, 20(5), 789–795. doi: 10.1175/waf884.1

[2] Steele, M., & Chaseling, J. (2006). Goodness-of-Fit Tests Powers of Discrete Goodness-of-Fit Test Statistics for a Uniform Null Against a Selection of Alternative Distributions.

someone can use Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for discrete histograms for non-parametric statistics. My question is can I use this python package: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kstest.html for the latter hypothesis test?

Comment: Please tell us what the "latter hypothesis test" is.  And what might a "non-parametric histogram" be?

Comment: A test based on a Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic could be used for binned data, but you generally can't use the usual null distribution and get close to a desired significance level. A permutation distribution could be used.

Comment: "latter hypothesis test" = "can someone use Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for discrete histograms??" and "non-parametric histogram" = "histograms with random (surely not common) distribution"

Comment: How many bins should the histograms have in order to use permutation test?